# Disable click propagation for href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code snippet explains my case:

```js
$("#b").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$("#b").click(function() {
  alert("trigger div");
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="stackoverflow.com" id="a">
  <div id="b">Test</div>
</a>
```

The problem is that I only want to trigger the click function from the `div` and not the `href` from the `a` tag. In a similar question I found `event.stopPropagation()`, but that does not work in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent the default click event action using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method.

```js
$("#b").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("trigger div");
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="stackoverflow.com" id="a">
  <div id="b">Test</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

$("#b").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("trigger div");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

without javascript:

```css
#a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="stackoverflow.com" id="a">
<a href="#"><div onclick="alert('trigger div')">test</div></a>
</a>
```